# Is there a way to subscribe to changes in window.getSelection?

Tags: javascript, webapi

We are able to get a selection range via `window.getSelection()`.
I'm wondering whether there is a way to subscribe to `window.getSelection` changes.

The only way which came to me is to use timeouts (which is obviously bad) or subscribe to each user's key \ mouse press event and track changes manually.

**ANSWER UPD:** You are able to use this library, I've published it, as there are no more suitable ones: https://github.com/xnimorz/selection-range-enhancer

Comment: what do you mean by subscribe changes ?

Comment: To track them in realtime like other events. The closest approach is to subscribe to the key \ mouse press event (with capture flag) and check if window.getSelection() result is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`onselect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect) event.

```js
function logSelection(event) {
  const log = document.getElementById('log');
  const selection = event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd);
  log.textContent = `You selected: ${selection}`;
}

const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.onselect = logSelection;
```

```html
<textarea>Try selecting some text in this element.</textarea>
<p id="log"></p>
```

For specific cases such as `span` `contenteditable`, you can make a polyfill:

```js
function logSelection() {
  const log = document.getElementById('log');
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  log.textContent = `You selected: ${selection}`;
}

const span = document.querySelector('span');

var down = false;
span.onmousedown = () => { down = true };
span.onmouseup = () => { down = false };
span.onmousemove = () => {
  if (down == true) {
    logSelection();
  }
};
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true">Try selecting some text in this element.</span>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only with textarea, but it's unable to track using contenteditable for instance

Comment: I changed the answer. Check the end :) ^

Comment: To make the full example it should have tracking of keyboards events also as a user could use SHIFT+arrows (I've already described it in the question topic). 

But I see, there are no smaller workarounds

Comment: That's right. Ideally it also should include touch events for mobile. There's no best way to do this with span.

Comment: btw, I've published a small library which fulfills my needs: https://github.com/xnimorz/selection-range-enhancer

Answer (score 0):

if Im undesrting in right way you want to know when user start selection on page you can use DOM onselectstart.

```
document.onselectstart = function() {
  console.log("Selection started!");
};
```

more info [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectstart)

Comment: onselectstart works perfectly if the user puts just a cursor, but you still have to use mouse events to track the selection range (as it track just a start position)

Comment: correct but if you provide more details in your question that will make easy to understand and will provide you with proper way. but your question is not clear.